# Geometry Errors with Imported Shapefile, Unable to Fix

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geocoding, topology, microsoft-power-map-excel

Software Used

- QGIS 2.18.10
- MS Excel 2016

GitHub Repository With Files ([link](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Graffiti))

## Update 3

Blank file when reprojecting

## 1. Open the layer

[image]

## 2. Double-click `Reproject Layer`

[image]

## 3. Select Reprojection Parameters

[image]

## 4. Reprojected layer is blank

[image]

## 5. Error when attempting to import to Excel 2016 Power Map

[image]

## 6. Directory of shapefile

[image]

---

---

## Update 2

Unable to find `Processing Tools`

Here is something close, but none of the three sub-categories ask for output shapefile.

[image]

---

---

---

#### Update 1

Here are steps ... it appears correct in QGIS but there are still `Invalid Geometry Errors` in Excel Power Map

NOTE: Just for grins, in Step 5 I saved using NY projection instead of WGS 84 projection and I get same error.

#### 1. Add Delimited Text Layer

[image]

#### 2. Select options > OK

[image]

#### 3. Select NY Projection

[image]

#### 4. Right-click > Save As

[image]

#### 5. Select WGS 84 Projection (what Excel accepts)

[image]

#### 6. Output

[image]

---

---

#### Original Question

I am trying to create shapefile with **DSNY_Graffiti_Information.csv**

Created Layer from delimited text file

Then I select New York Projection (EPSG:2263)

Finally I save as shapefile in **NY_Graffiti_Shapefile.zip**

When I attempt to import shapefile to MS Excel 2016 Power Maps I get Invalid regions error

[image]

Attempted to use [Topology Checker Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/it/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html), but no errors are detected.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What projection are you using? Your csv is fine. I just created a shapefile from it in ArcGIS, so it has to be a problem related to the projection you're using in QGIS and Excel. Maybe you're not using the same one for both?

Comment: @SergioC. I tried with projections WGS84 and New York Projection (EPSG:2263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2015/05/18/power-map-for-excel-may-update-for-office-365/):

> The Custom Regions feature in Power Map allows you to import KML or
>   SHP files which contain custom *polygons*.

Since you're trying to import *point* geometry that would explain the `Invalid Geometry` error.

You could try running a buffer on the points in QGIS to convert them into small circles which might make it acceptable to Excel.

Comment: Am researching how to buffer ...

Comment: Having trouble with buffer. I posted new question just for this. Please assist, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246416/how-to-run-buffer-on-qgis-points

Answer (score 1):

Before importing to Excel, make sure you define the projection in QGIS. Select the layer properties --> general --> Reference system and find the New York projection EPSG 2263.

Then right click on the layer again and select save as: The result should be a valid shapefile. I did it myself and works well both in QGIS and ArcGIS. Unfortenately, I don't have a license for Excel Power Maps so I can't try it there, but if ArcGIS opens it, the shapefile should be fine.

Comment: Hello @sergio-c I'm trying this now ...

Comment: I tried, still not working. Please see updated question for screenshots -- perhaps I overlooked something?

Comment: You should save your shapefile without changing the projection to wgs 1984 but keeping the New York one. That's what making Excel to be "confused". Once you have saved your shapefile, you need to convert it to wgs 1984, you'll get a second shp that you will add to excel. You will find the reproject tool under "processing tools".

Comment: Unable to find processing tools. Closest thing I can find is Raster > Projections but neither Warp,Assign Projection, nor Extract Projection ask for shapefile or projection. Please see question under Update 2

Comment: Try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218554/99720

Comment: For some reason it's not working. Please see Update 3 to question.

Comment: The reprojected layer is not blank, just moved. Right click the layer and select "zoom to layer"

Comment: I'll try this .... FYI when I tried imported to Excel it gave error .... will try though ....

Comment: The second answer by Mark may give you the clue. Try to buffer the reprojected layer to get small polygons instead of points. Search "how to buffer points with qgis" if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes I'm trying the buffer route also. Posted separated question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246416/how-to-run-buffer-on-qgis-points